# Hadith by Ibn Abbas in a tafsir of Ibn Kathir

Tags: hadith, tafseer

I came accross this hadith that is attributed to Ibn Abbas in a tafsir by Ibn Kathir.

[Ibn Abi Hatim recorded that Ibn `Abbas said, "The sun is like flowing water, running in its course in the sky during the day. When it sets, it travels in its course beneath the earth until it rises in the east.'' He said, "The same is true in the case of the moon.'']

I came across an explanation of why the hadith is not considered to be authentic.

https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/336679/ibn-abbaas-statement-about-motion-of-sun

I would like it if someone could better elaborate why the hadith is not considered authentic (even though Ibn Kathir thought the chain of narrators was authentic).

Comment: Additionally, some of the transmitters in the chain also have issues, such as Abu Saleh (Abdullah bin Saleh) the scribe of Laith. To consider it authentic is a lenient position, not everyone would agree to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a statement of Ibn Abbas (RA), not the Prophet (SAW).

So, even if the chain is authentic, that just means Ibn Abbas said it. Ibn Abbas does not have infinite knowledge, nor is he a prophet, nor are his interpretations necessarily binding in stories and unnecessary details.

The information is not something authentic to the Prophet.